# Unit testing capture failure not shown in istanbul code coverage

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js, istanbul

I'm trying to capture an error with my tests. I have istanbul showing that a current path is not covered by my tests. I think I have it covered but I'm curious why it's not showing in my coverage report.

This is the bit of code i'm testing, It says that my error if route is never covered.

```
pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
if (err) {
  console.log(err.message)
  return false
}
else{
   console.log('Connected!!');
 }
});
```

and here is the test I have for that

```
it("Should fail to provide a test database connection" , function(done){
let pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 200,
  host     : '***',
  user     : 'correctuser',
  password : 'WRONGPASSWORD',
  database : 'db'
});
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
  if(err){
    console.log(err.message);
    done();
  }
});
})
```

Comment: A little observation: Use mocks to test your server connections

Answer (score 0):

You're not currently checking if your server connection throws an error

Check this for Chai.js: [Expect/Should](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_throw) and [Assert](http://chaijs.com/api/assert/#method_istrue).